# XML parsing from local xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing, local

I'm parsing XML from URL. What changes has been made to parse same XML file from raw folder. Have any idea to how to reduce code ?

This my xml file :umesh.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appdata>
<brand name="Lovely Products">
<product>Hat</product>
<product>Gloves</product>
</brand>
<brand name="Great Things">
<product>Table</product>
<product>Chair</product>
<product>Bed</product>
</brand>
</appdata>
```

Below is my java file :

1. **DataHandler.java**

   ```
   package com.umesh.xmlparsing;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.net.URLConnection;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
   import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

   import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
   import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
   import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
   import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
   import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
   import android.graphics.Color;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.TextView;



   public class DataHandler extends DefaultHandler{

   //list for imported product data
   private ArrayList<TextView> theViews;
   //string to track each entry
   private String currBrand = "";
   //flag to keep track of XML processing
   private boolean isProduct = false;
   //context for user interface
   private Context theContext;
   //constructor
   public DataHandler(Context cont) {
       super();
       theViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();
       theContext = cont;
   }


   //start of the XML document
   public void startDocument () { Log.i("DataHandler", "Start of XML document"); }

   //end of the XML document
   public void endDocument () { Log.i("DataHandler", "End of XML document"); }

   //opening element tag
   public void startElement (String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
   {
       //handle the start of an element

       //find out if the element is a brand
       if(qName.equals("brand"))
       {
           //set product tag to false
           isProduct = false;
           //create View item for brand display
           TextView brandView = new TextView(theContext);
           brandView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(73, 136, 83));
           //add the attribute value to the displayed text
           String viewText = "Items from " + atts.getValue("name") + ":";
           brandView.setText(viewText);
           //add the new view to the list
           theViews.add(brandView);
       }
       //the element is a product
       else if(qName.equals("product"))
           isProduct = true;
   }

   //closing element tag
   public void endElement (String uri, String name, String qName)
   {
       //handle the end of an element
       if(qName.equals("brand"))
       {
           //create a View item for the products
           TextView productView = new TextView(theContext);
           productView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(192, 199, 95));
           //display the compiled items
           productView.setText(currBrand);
           //add to the list
           theViews.add(productView);
           //reset the variable for future items
           currBrand = "";
       }
   }

   //element content
   public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length)
   {
       //process the element content
       //string to store the character content
       String currText = "";
       //loop through the character array
       for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++)
       {
           switch (ch[i]) {
           case '\\':
               break;
           case '"':
               break;
           case '\n':
               break;
           case '\r':
               break;
           case '\t':
               break;
           default:
               currText += ch[i];
               break;
           }
       }
       //prepare for the next item
       if(isProduct && currText.length()>0)
           currBrand += currText+"\n";
   }

   public ArrayList<TextView> getData()
   {
       //take care of SAX, input and parsing errors
       try
       {
               //set the parsing driver
           System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver","org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
               //create a parser
           SAXParserFactory parseFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser xmlParser = parseFactory.newSAXParser();
               //get an XML reader
           XMLReader xmlIn = xmlParser.getXMLReader();
               //instruct the app to use this object as the handler
           xmlIn.setContentHandler(this);
               //provide the name and location of the XML file **ALTER THIS FOR YOUR FILE**
           URL xmlURL = new URL("http://mydomain.com/umesh.xml");


               //open the connection and get an input stream
           URLConnection xmlConn = xmlURL.openConnection();
           InputStreamReader xmlStream = new InputStreamReader(xmlConn.getInputStream());

               //build a buffered reader
           BufferedReader xmlBuff = new BufferedReader(xmlStream);

           //   uuu   XmlResourceParser todolistXml = getResources().getXml(R.raw.c4mh_clinics);
               //parse the data
           xmlIn.parse(new InputSource(xmlBuff));
       }
       catch(SAXException se) { Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity", 
               "SAX Error " + se.getMessage()); }
       catch(IOException ie) { Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity", 
               "Input Error " + ie.getMessage()); }
       catch(Exception oe) { Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity", 
               "Unspecified Error " + oe.getMessage()); }
           //return the parsed product list
       return theViews;
   }

   }
   ```
2. **XMLParsing.java**

   ```
   package com.umesh.xmlparsing;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class XMLParsing extends Activity {

   TextView tv;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //get a reference to the layout
       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);
       try
       {
               //create an instance of the DefaultHandler class 
               //**ALTER THIS FOR YOUR CLASS NAME**
           DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(getApplicationContext());
               //get the string list by calling the public method
           ArrayList<TextView> newViews = handler.getData();
               //convert to an array
           Object[] products = newViews.toArray();
               //loop through the items, creating a View item for each
           for(int i=0; i<products.length; i++)
           {
               //add the next View in the list
               mainLayout.addView((TextView)products[i]);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception pce) { Log.e("AndroidTestsActivity", "PCE "+pce.getMessage()); }

       setContentView(mainLayout);
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: Umesh, you should save your data in a custom class. A textview has internal variables that'll take up memory though you won't be needing it. Also have you tried a ListView? It'll reduce your code significantly.

Comment: This code read xml from url, can you edit my code so that it can read from local raw folder..

Comment: Just repalce ` xmlIn.parse(new InputSource(xmlBuff));` with ` xmlIn.parse(getResources().openRawresource(id));` Not sure if parse has a InputStream parameterized overloaded function, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please See below link of my answer, it will solve your problem.

[Local XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435177/load-local-xml-data-in-listview-in-android/12435481#12435481)

Comment: It works for me......I have just change one line..   InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.localxmlfileName);   with  InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localxmlfileName);  Because res word does not resolve. I dont know why..But finaly done.. Thanks a lot.. It is very simple code and reduce coding...

Comment: But it shows output as Hat Table. I want to show output in group i.e first group products and below that second group products.