# How to get XML from local res/raw folder?

Tags: android

While doing this task I followed XML Parsing tutorial from http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/
Very good tutorial. One minus for me it is taking XML from URL. I need to take from R.raw folder. I searched for solutions, found many solutions with InputStream(eg: [Load local xml data in listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435177/load-local-xml-data-in-listview-in-android/12435481#12435481))
I have put one line of code

```
InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.localxmlfileName);
```

But it is underlining res and giving mistake:[res cannot be resolved]. How to solve this problem and am I going right way?

Comment: I really recommend putting your custom XML in `res/xml/`, not `res/raw/`, and then use `getXml()` on a `Resources` object to read it in. This will run about 10x faster, if not more, than the approach that you are describing.

Comment: can you write line of code how to do it?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For XML, a generally better option is to put the file in `res/xml/`, then get an `XmlPullParser` for that XML by calling `getResources().getXml()`. The `XmlPullParser` allows you to work your way through the XML events (new document, new element, etc.) and read in what you need.

For example, given `res/xml/words.xml` like this:

```
<words>
  <word value="lorem" />
  <word value="ipsum" />
  <word value="dolor" />
  <word value="sit" />
  <word value="amet" />
  <word value="consectetuer" />
  <word value="adipiscing" />
  <word value="elit" />
  <word value="morbi" />
  <word value="vel" />
  <word value="ligula" />
  <word value="vitae" />
  <word value="arcu" />
  <word value="aliquet" />
  <word value="mollis" />
  <word value="etiam" />
  <word value="vel" />
  <word value="erat" />
  <word value="placerat" />
  <word value="ante" />
  <word value="porttitor" />
  <word value="sodales" />
  <word value="pellentesque" />
  <word value="augue" />
  <word value="purus" />
</words>
```

you would read them into an `ArrayList<String>` like this (from inside an activity, for example):

```
  ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
  XmlPullParser xpp=getResources().getXml(R.xml.words);

  while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
      if (xpp.getName().equals("word")) {
        items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
      }
    }

    xpp.next();
  }
```

(there's a `try`/`catch` block in there too, but I trimmed that out for the sake of simplicity)

The advantage is that XML stored in a `res/xml/` can be read in this way about ten times faster than using an XML parser on an `InputStream` from `res/raw/`, or from a plain file. That's because Google seriously optimized the act of reading in XML from resource directories known to hold XML (`res/xml/`, `res/layout/`, etc.), partly by pre-compiling the XML in to a "binary XML" format as part of the build process.

The disadvantage is that fewer developers are familiar with `XmlPullParser`.

Comment: We always get something new to learn from you. Thanks sir for enlightening us new developers.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer with examples. How to implement ArrayList<> items into ListView?

Comment: @JoeRichard: Use an `ArrayAdapter<>`.

Comment: OK. What if listview includes more than one textview. I mean one list item has 3 characteristics:name, description, and price. What should I write if I will use ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); //instead of// ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<String>(); //because it is showing error while adding item into items [items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0)); //underlining add]. please help

Comment: Sorry for hard to understand question. I meant that how to implement items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0)); if one list view item has more than one text views?

Comment: @JoeRichard: This is getting *way* beyond comments on the answer. I would recommend that you create some sort of model object that holds your strings, then create an `ArrayAdapter<WhateverYourModelIs>`, where you can override `getView()` to populate multiple widgets in your row. If you have further questions on setting up an `ArrayAdapter`, please start another StackOverflow question, after having searched for existing materials first.

Answer (score 1):

`res` seems to be a resource variable. You need to get the resources first. Try using something like:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localxmlfileName);
```

Comment: Now it is showing openRawResource as error(underlining:undefined for the type of object). No idea what to do

Comment: InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pizza);
   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
   //InputSource is = new InputSource();
      is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
      doc = db.parse(is);

Comment: You might need a context for that. So try `this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localxmlfileName);` if you are doing it inside a class which extends `Activity` else you need to get the `Contect` somehow.

Comment: class extends Activity and i have put this. before getResources() it still showing error. what to do?